# create unique ID using R

Tags: r

I have a question to create unique consumer_id using R.

Here is the expected data set.The original data has name and order_no.

```
name order_no. consumer_id
a     #1000     1
      #1000     1
      #1000     1
b     #1001     2
c     #1002     3
      #1002     3
d     #1003     4
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `dat$consumer_id <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$order_no))`? It's tough to tell exactly what sort of data you have without the output of something like `dput(dat)` for your data frame `dat`.

Comment: @josliber the original data has name and order_no.,but I want to create new id with unique consumer_id,like 3rd column.

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure the duplicate I marked (and the code in my comment) do what you're asking; if not please edit your question to give more details about how the consumer_id is generated from the data.